# order by date starting from current month in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a **date** type column in *mysql* table. I need to order the date starting from the current month independent of year.

**tblEvent**

```
event_date
__________
2016-01-07
2016-01-13
2016-05-16
2016-05-22
2016-05-30
2018-06-21
2016-06-23
2016-07-14
2018-08-16
2016-10-20
1990-12-09
2016-12-15
```

As the current month is Jun therefore, the required **Output** should be:

```
event_date
__________
2018-06-21
2016-06-23
2016-07-14
2018-08-16
2016-10-20
1990-12-09
2016-12-15
2016-01-07
2016-01-13
2016-05-16
2016-05-22
2016-05-30
```

1. Order must **start from the current month** 
   month
2. for example if the current month is ***Nov*** then the order must be
   ***Nov, Dec, Jan, Feb, Mar, ....., Oct***
3. also the respective *dates must be in asc order*.
4. order must be **independent of year**(i.e. no matter what year is there
   in the date)

Comment: What query you try so far?

Comment: Sorry @Deepak, but they are filtering the record of the current month only I need to list all the months starting from the current. Kindly refer the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT event_date
FROM tblEvent
ORDER BY
 IF(MONTH(event_date) < MONTH(NOW()), MONTH(event_date) + 12, MONTH(event_date)),
 DAY(event_date)
```

Info:

- [Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [Control Flow Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html)

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, a soultion can be like this:

```
select
  event_date
from
  tblevent
order by
  (12+month(event_date)-month(current_date)) mod 12,
  day(event_date)
```

this query will sort all rows starting from the current month, ordered by month and day not considering the year. Please see a working fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/463f8e/1).

Answer (score 0):

I just try below query, Getting all records, starts from current month in desc order. like:- month 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1

```
SELECT *
FROM `schedules`
WHERE date_format( `ScheduleDate` , "%m" ) <= date_format( NOW( ) , "%m" )
ORDER BY `ScheduleDate` DESC
LIMIT 0 , 30;
```

You can try in this way, Hope this will help.